# echoing back links without tags

Tags: php, mysql

I have a url input field where untagged text gets stored as a link like this:

```
$newwebsiteurl = '<a target="_blank" href="http://' .$_POST['newwebsiteurl']
                  . '">' .   $_POST['newwebsiteurl'] . '</a>';
```

but now I want another form where the data can be edited and I want to echo back the information(from mysql) without the tags so basically the inverse of the above code  I need to do something like this:

```
             echo $info['category']
```

minus this part:

```
                <a target="_blank" href="http://
                <a target="_blank" href="xxxxx">*show_this_part_only*</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`echo str_replace("/http:\/\//","",$_POST['newwebsiteurl']");`

For more clarity :

```
<a target="_blank" href="<?php echo $_POST['newwebsiteurl']; ?>"><?php echo str_replace("/http:\/\//","",$_POST['newwebsiteurl']"); ?></a>
```

Comment: I'm getting 'unexpected "" parse error'

Comment: try the newly revised, post the entire error you are getting

Comment: the thing is I can't define the post variables as they have already been posted

Comment: so save them before hand `$mypost =$_POST['newwebsiteurl'];` then just replace `$mypost` for `$_POST['newwebsiteurl']"); `

Answer (score 0):

Just don't save the HTML tags in SQL in the first place and only add them when displaying it (if I understood you correctly that is).

Comment: that would work, only assuming he doesn't need that data for something else :X

Comment: What data are you talking about? All extra data needed can just be added when displaying the link. Or did I miss something here?

Comment: I'm actually unsure whether he's exclusing just `http://` or something else (depending on situation), my answer only excludes `http://`

Comment: @OP could you please clarify what you are trying to do?

Comment: basically just trying to remove <href> tags when echoing the data

Comment: @user1559811 If that is the case see my answer :)

Comment: but I need it to be stored that way fro other purposes on the site

Comment: @user1559811 No you do not. It is considered *bad* practice to do that.